# Install Active Directory without needing RSAT

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershellget

## Installing Active Directory in Servers without RSAT

> I am able to install Active Directory module in some servers but not
> in others....

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-Module -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck .\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll -ErrorAction Continue -Force
Install-Module -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck .\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.resources.dll -ErrorAction Continue -Force
```

### I keep getting this error:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified 
search criteria and module name 
'D:\install\ADPoSh\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.resources.dll'. Try 
Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 
char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPacka 
   ge:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.Pac 
   kageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I simply copied the DLLs from the WinSXS folder on a system that has the RSAT AD Module and the C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveDirectory, all into the same folder.
What am I missing here?

Comment: What reply do you get from `Get-PSRepository` on the machines that won't install? You;re better off troubleshooting that that trying to copy files over to get it working

Comment: @Scepticalist WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

Answer (score 1):

## Import-Module, not Install-Module

Wow, the answer was as simple as *not using Install-Module*, after the RSAT Feature install and merely running Import-Module instead! :)

### So NOT THIS:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-AD-PowerShell|Install-Windowsfeature
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-Module ActiveDirectory -Proxy proxy.verizon.com:80
```

### But This:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-AD-PowerShell|Install-Windowsfeature
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Proxy proxy.verizon.com:80
```

I mean, I would like to fix the repo, but, hey, AD Module works now so... yeah!

Comment: BTW:
#For the reason for the next line read:
#https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ozr6ye/psa_enabling_tls12_and_you/ 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12